# Query response time with WHERE and HAVING

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, where-clause, having

I have a simple SQL request:

```
SELECT id, title, resum
FROM film
WHERE id = 56 ;
```

The response time for this request is nearly equal to 0.0009 sec

Whereas, the same query, using Having Clause :

```
SELECT id, title, resum
FROM film
HAVING id =56 ;
```

Give such a big response time compered with the 1st request (0.0049 sec).

The 1st request is more optimized, But, Why ? 
Can you tell me the reason that cause this big difference ?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, let's state the most important thing: Your second query isn't a valid SQL query as it uses the [MySQL GROUP BY extensions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html). When you switch off this MySQL extension with

```
SET SESSION sql_mode='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';
```

then you'll get an error like this:

```
ERROR 1463 (42000): non-grouping field 'id' is used in HAVING clause
```

So, you should really use the `WHERE` clause.

But now to your actual question. I assume from your measurements, that there is an index on the "id" field. Because `HAVING` works (should work) on grouped data, there's no index it could use. I've got a MySQL table here with about 1.2 million rows. A `HAVING` query on an indexed integer field takes 16 seconds on its first run and still about 0.6 seconds on consecutive calls, whereas the query using `WHERE` just takes 0.04 seconds.

Using `EXPLAIN`, MySQL will tell you that it doesn't use an index:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT id, title, resum FROM film HAVING id =56;
```

As an example, here are the results from `EXPLAIN` for the queries on my table:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT id, Title FROM `test` HAVING id = 4374354;
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------+
| id | select_type | table    | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra |
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | test     | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1201750 |       |
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------+
```

You see, the "key" field states "NULL", telling you that there isn't any index used. The "rows" field tells you instead, that MySQL traverses 1201750 (all) rows.

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT id, Title FROM `test` WHERE id = 4374354;
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table    | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | test     | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | const |    1 |       |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+
```

On the other hand, the `EXPLAIN` for `WHERE` tells us, that it uses the "PRIMARY" index and thus it just has to read a single row, resulting in a much faster response.